# Retrieve youtube subscriptions python api

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to use youtube-api to retrieve list of my youtube subscriptions and other data from just command line using python (without display), after reading google developer docs I realized ouath 2 needs user interface but there's also a [plugin](https://github.com/Kolifanes/plugin.video.youtube/) available for kodi that uses youtube tv for interacting with youtube and i think it could be usefull iny my case.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking?

Comment: I want a list of channels i have subscribed to, using only python

Comment: "I think it can be useful for my case." Well, try it out then ask if any problem occurs.

Comment: it was very poor documented and can't figure it out

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned in order to retrieve a list of your subscriptions, you need to first authenticate and authorize your application or script to "read" your subscriptions. Once this is done, you'll be able to retrieve your YouTube subscriptions using the YouTube Subscriptions Data API list method:
[Subscriptions: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list)

Using a modified version of the Python example code for the YouTube Subscriptions Data API insert method [Subscriptions: insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/insert#examples) the following code will authenticate and authorise a user, and then having been authorised, retrieve all the YouTube subscriptions for the authorized user.

While the code below does not explicitly work using command line arguments, there is no reason why it should not work using command line arguments, should you choose to use them. Several of the Google YouTube API Python examples have code to this effect.

```
# coding: utf-8
# https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list

import math
import os
import sys

import httplib2
from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.errors import HttpError
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.tools import argparser, run_flow

# The CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE variable specifies the name of a file that contains
# the OAuth 2.0 information for this application, including its client_id and
# client_secret. You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from
# the Google Developers Console at
# https://console.developers.google.com/.
# Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
# For more information about using OAuth2 to access the YouTube Data API, see:
#   https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication
# For more information about the client_secrets.json file format, see:
#   https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets
CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secrets.json"

# This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows for full read/write access to the
# authenticated user's account.
YOUTUBE_READ_WRITE_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"

# This variable defines a message to display if the CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE is
# missing.
MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE = """
WARNING: Please configure OAuth 2.0

To make this sample run you will need to populate the client_secrets.json file
found at:

   {}

with information from the Developers Console
https://console.developers.google.com/

For more information about the client_secrets.json file format, please visit:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets
""".format(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                                        CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE)))


def retrieve_youtube_subscriptions():
    # In order to retrieve the YouTube subscriptions for the current user,
    # the user needs to authenticate and authorize access to their YouTube
    # subscriptions.
    youtube_authorization = get_authenticated_service()

    try:
        # init
        next_page_token = ''
        subs_iteration = 0
        while True:
            # retrieve the YouTube subscriptions for the authorized user
            subscriptions_response = youtube_subscriptions(youtube_authorization, next_page_token)
            subs_iteration += 1
            total_results = subscriptions_response['pageInfo']['totalResults']
            results_per_page = subscriptions_response['pageInfo']['resultsPerPage']
            total_iterations = math.ceil(total_results / results_per_page)
            print('Subscriptions iteration: {} of {} ({}%)'.format(subs_iteration,
                                                                   total_iterations,
                                                                   round(subs_iteration / total_iterations * 100),
                                                                   0))
            # get the token for the next page if there is one
            next_page_token = get_next_page(subscriptions_response)
            # extract the required subscription information
            channels = parse_youtube_subscriptions(subscriptions_response)
            # add the channels relieved to the main channel list
            all_channels.extend(channels)
            if not next_page_token:
                break
        return all_channels

    except HttpError as err:
        print("An HTTP error {} occurred:\n{}".format(err.resp.status, err.content))


def get_authenticated_service():
    # Create a Storage instance to store and retrieve a single
    # credential to and from a file. Used to store the
    # oauth2 credentials for the current python script.
    storage = Storage("{}-oauth2.json".format(sys.argv[0]))
    credentials = storage.get()

    # Validate the retrieved oauth2 credentials
    if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
        # Create a Flow instance from a client secrets file
        flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE,
                                       scope=YOUTUBE_READ_WRITE_SCOPE,
                                       message=MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE)
        # The run_flow method requires arguments.
        # Initial default arguments are setup in tools, and any
        # additional arguments can be added from the command-line
        # and passed into this method.
        args = argparser.parse_args()
        # Obtain valid credentials
        credentials = run_flow(flow, storage, args)

    # Build and return a Resource object for interacting with an YouTube API
    return build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME,
                 YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
                 http=credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()))


# Call youtube.subscriptions.list method
# to list the channels subscribed to.
def youtube_subscriptions(youtube, next_page_token):
    subscriptions_response = youtube.subscriptions().list(
        part='snippet',
        mine=True,
        maxResults=50,
        order='alphabetical',
        pageToken=next_page_token).execute()
    return subscriptions_response


def get_next_page(subscriptions_response):
    # check if the subscription response contains a reference to the
    # next page or not
    if 'nextPageToken' in subscriptions_response:
        next_page_token = subscriptions_response['nextPageToken']
    else:
        next_page_token = ''
    return next_page_token


def parse_youtube_subscriptions(subscriptions_response):
    channels = []

    # Add each result to the appropriate list
    for subscriptions_result in subscriptions_response.get("items", []):
        if subscriptions_result["snippet"]["resourceId"]["kind"] == "youtube#channel":
            channels.append("{} ({})".format(subscriptions_result["snippet"]["title"],
                                             subscriptions_result["snippet"]["resourceId"]["channelId"]))

    return channels


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # init
    all_channels = []

    print('Perform youtube subscriptions')
    # retrieve subscriptions
    all_channels = retrieve_youtube_subscriptions()
    print('Subscriptions complete')
    print('Subscriptions found: {}'.format(len(all_channels)))

    print("Channels:\n", "\n".join(all_channels), "\n")
```

**Note:** As a once off action, the above code, if it does not find authorized credentials for a user, will open a local URL and redirect to Google for authentication.

**Additional Prerequisites:**

1. For the above Python 3 code to work, the "google-api-python-client-py3" package needs to be installed using pip.
2. A client_secrets.json file needs to be created. This is done by following the instructions at the top of the python script.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`Activities:list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities/list) this method returns a list of channel activity events that match the request criteria. For example, you can retrieve events associated with a particular channel, events associated with the user's subscriptions and Google+ friends, or the YouTube home page feed, which is customized for each user.

**HTTP request**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/activities
```

Under the [`Subscription:list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list) returns subscription resources that match the API request data.

If successful, this method returns a response body with the following structure:

```
{
"kind": "youtube#subscriptionListResponse",
"etag": etag,
"nextPageToken": string,
"prevPageToken": string,
"pageInfo": {
"totalResults": integer,
"resultsPerPage": integer
},
"items": [
subscription Resource
]
}
```